# Forecast pricing data with lead times?

Tags: forecasting

I have some "big data" containing event pricing information with 45 days of lead time quotes up to the day before the event. Thus, it's structured like so:

-45 100.00
-44 120.00
...
-1 110.00

We have events every day of the year, and have year-over-year data. I'm a relative newbie to forecasting models, so this is a basic question: is it possible to use this data to perform forecasting? What would be a good model to use to do this?